# Uploading new files to a Git repository directly through the GitHub web application

Tags: git, github

It is possible to directly edit files in a repository stored on GitHub through the web interface. Most of us would never do this but it has its uses.

[image: Edit button on GitHub]

I teach an introductory level course. I'd like to use Git and GitHub for homework distribution and collection (GitHub offers free private accounts for education). However, I can't ask completely fresh students to learn Git, at least not in the first few weeks. For the first few weeks I would like to say

> "You can upload your homework by clicking on this sequence of buttons on github.com"

and then eventually teach them how to use the command line.

Ideally I'd like for them to be able to upload new files, not just edit existing ones. I can't find a way to do this though. How can I use the GitHub web interface for a similar purpose?

Comment: Is using http://gist.github.com an option?

Comment: Gist is a good idea. Ideally though I'd like to transition to having the students use git proper. I'd also like to interact with their code via command line (for feedback, help with HW, etc...) and use leave comments on the commits.

Comment: Have the students use the GitHub application for Windows or Mac. It will be easier than the command line.

Comment: @asmeurer It's often buggy. I'm almost never able to use that.

Comment: That feature just evolved yesterday (February 2016). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35500082/6309)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that since early December 2012, you can create **[new files directly from GitHub](https://github.com/blog/1327-creating-files-on-github)**:

[image: Create new File]

> **ProTip™**: You can pre-fill the filename field using just the URL.
>   Typing `?filename=yournewfile.txt` at the end of the URL will pre-fill the filename field with the name `yournewfile.txt`.

[image: d]

Comment: create is not an upload

Comment: And what if you wanted a non-text file to be uploaded?

Comment: @user2813274 Did you find any solution for binary files?

Answer (score 8):

Since February 2016, you can add/create/**upload** new files from the GitHub web interface.

See "[Upload files to your repositories](https://github.com/blog/2105-upload-files-to-your-repositories) ":

> You can click the “Upload files” button in the toolbar at the top of the file tree.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1369864/12961550/b9a688ea-d006-11e5-96d3-ac91097192a5.png]

> Or, you can drag and drop files from your desktop onto the file tree.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1369864/12961164/a888b59e-d004-11e5-80a6-e9f32f17c4d5.gif]

This replaces the file creation described in [the 2012 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13736450/6309), and add the upload capability (for one or several files).

Answer (score 2):

I think using [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com) is the easiest option. Each gist is a Git repository that can be accessed from the web browser or from the shell, there's a comment button, and although gists are usually single files, they can hold multiple files.

The drawbacks to gists are obviously the cryptic URLs and the fact that you have to copy-paste file contents into the browser unless you use a [separate tool](http://defunkt.io/gist/).

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to have them edit the same files (assumedly through the web interface), you could create a skeleton repository with empty or basic files, and then have the students fork that.

Answer (score 0):

If you start a new project without a README file, it won't show.

You need at least one file in it. As it's shown in previous answers, you can drag your files or select it using finder or file explorer.