# Upload a binary file using browser to github?

Tags: github, binaryfiles

How do I upload a new binary file to Github?

I try to upload some `woff` fonts, but I cant, because Github allow me only to add a text file, and not how to upload one, even if there [is this request that was solved.](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/694)

Comment: The mentioned ticket is not related to Github's web interface at all.

Comment: that was just an example. so that means that it is not possible? only with `console` ?

Comment: Only by pushing as a regular git commit via git cli or using one of the available git gui tool

Comment: so sadly not possible using the browser?

Comment: Yes, as far as i know.

Comment: I hope they will add this option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Since February 2016, you can add/create/*upload* new files from GitHub web interface**.

You should *not* upload (big) binary files (they should be generated as part of a release, see second part of this answer).

But the feature (upload a file, any file) is there.
See "[Upload files to your repositories](https://github.com/blog/2105-upload-files-to-your-repositories) ":

> You can click the “Upload files” button in the toolbar at the top of the file tree.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1369864/12961550/b9a688ea-d006-11e5-96d3-ac91097192a5.png]

> Or, you can drag and drop files from your desktop onto the file tree.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1369864/12961164/a888b59e-d004-11e5-80a6-e9f32f17c4d5.gif]

This replaces the file creation described in [the 2012 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13736450/6309), and add the **upload** capability (for one or several files).

---

Original answer (March 2015)

The only part of the GitHub web interface which allows you to push a binary (or any other file you want) is when [**creating a release**](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/).
Then, there is a step where you can drag and drop any binary you need:

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/releases/releases_adding_binary.gif]

But for a regular repo, when [**creating new files**](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-new-files/), you can only *edit* a new file, not drag&drop an existing binary content:

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/new-file-content.png]

<del>So it isn't possible for now (March 2015)</del>

---

Answer (score 0):

As today (19-02-2016), this option is available!

[image]